# Margin being added on h2

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a div that has a button on the left, right and then a header in between. Something that looks like this:

[image]

But I'm getting something like this:

[image]

You can see that there is a margin being added and I can't figure out why. I have inspected everything I can, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. (I understand that the `h2` is at 50%. I did this to try and figure out why the right button was being pushed down.)

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="day_buttons">
            <button id="previous_day"></button>
            <h2 id="zip_h2">What day and time would you like your stuff picked up?</h2>
            <button id="next_day"></button>
    </div><!--end nav_buttons-->
```

Here is the CSS to go with it:

```
#next_day
{
    float: right;
    background: transparent url(./images/icons/forward_button.gif) no-repeat top left;
    width:4em;
    height:4em;
    z-index:5;

}

#previous_day
{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float: left;
    background: transparent url(./images/icons/backward_button.gif) no-repeat top left;
    width:4em;
    height:4em;
    z-index:5;
}
.day_buttons
{
    height:3em;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#zip_h2
{
    width: 50%;
    margin:0px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle for those who need it: http://jsfiddle.net/tK72Z/

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: @JackWilliams I added the fiddle.

Comment: @Blaine there won't be any margin if you set the position of the left button to absolute

Comment: @VarunDas that isn't true. The margin will still exist, but the button will be placed on top of the margin. Essentially, the margin won't matter. But it will still exist. I would like to eliminate the margin if possible. Using absolute positioning isn't great for responsive web sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H2` elements are **block-level** so it will always try to fill 100% of the width on the "line" unless you tell it not to.

Just add `float:left` to your `h2` styling and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
#zip_h2
{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

OR

```
#zip_h2
{
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="day_buttons">
    <button id="previous_day"></button>
    <h2 id="zip_h2">What day and time would you like your stuff picked up?</h2>
    <button id="next_day"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.day_buttons
{
  position: relative;
}

.day_buttons h2
{
  text-align: center;
}

.day_buttons button
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.day_buttons #previous_day
{
  left: 0;
}

.day_buttons #next_day
{
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the CSS :

**For the right button**

```
#next_day
{
position: absolute;
float: right;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
background: transparent url(right.jpg) no-repeat top left;
width:4em;
height:4em;
z-index:5;  
}
```

**For the heading**

```
#zip_h2
{
margin:0px !important;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 70px;
text-align: center;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small Change

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tK72Z/2/)